# Currency of CDS and adjustment of interest rated for country risk

Tags: risk, cds, currency, adjustments

I have question concered currency of the CDS spreads.

In the analysis I am conducting, I perform adjustment of interest rates for country risk (CDS could be a reference to reflect a country risk).

I have bond issued in USA for e.g. 5Y with interest rate WIBOR 6M + margin 500 bp (now it is expressed as WIBOR – previously it was fixed rate but I converted it via some swap pricer into WIBOR).
CDS for USA 5Y is let’s say 21,07 bp **EUR** and for Poland 5Y 56,52 **USD** bp. Then I would like to perform adjustment of interest rate for country risk - so I would like to get margin level which should be if the bond would issued in Poland instead of USA. So I would like to make the following adjustment: 500 bp + (56,52-21,07) = 535,45 bp <-- this should be value of the analyzed bond’s margin as if it was issued in Poland instead of USA.

My questions are about the currencies of the CDS spreads used to conduct the above adjustment:

1. Should the CDS Spreads be in the same currency if I make the calculation (56,52 **USD** vs. 21,07 **EUR**)? I.e. Is it possible to compare the CDS Spreads in different currency?
2. If the currency should be the same, then which currency should be taken as a reference, as some CDS spreads are expressed in USD or EUR?
3. **Or maybe I should convert each CDS Spread to PLN as the base rate of adjusted bond is polish WIBOR + margin?**

With this approach I have doubt that if the CDS Spread would be expressed in PLN then the CDS for USA and PL would amount to: (i) USA: 96,29 PLN, (ii) PL: 238,68 PLN. Then the adjustment for country risk would be as follows: 500 bp + (238,68 - 96,29) = 642,39 bp. This means that adjustment would be higher that using for example EUR or USD currency.

BR,
Damian

Comment: The EUR CDS spread is so much tighter than the USD CDS (referencing the same hard-currency debt) because if Poland soveregn defaults, then EUR would devalue versus USD and other currencies, and the protection buyer's notional payoff would be worth less; while USD probably would react less. If PLN -denominated quanto CDS (referencing the same hard-currency debt) were liquid, then it would be even tighter than the EUR one (because under the default scenario PLN would devalue even more than EUR). But I don't see a tradable instrument to observe this PLAN "quanto factor".

Comment: This isn't an easy subject for most to grasp unless they've had previous exposure to quanto.
 
@DimitriVulis exactly correct in his comment and provides a nice intuitive explanation of the main dynamic here.

Here's a paper that has way more info than you need.  Don't get hung up on the various specific models they list.  You want to first cement your intuitive understanding of how the correlation between currency moves and default risks should drive pricing: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.07256.pdf

Comment: If only it were that simple :-) even with Italy, Spain etc.,there are two different CDS’s, the D5 and D13 (if I recall), one of which covers novation risk, which the other does not. The spread being one measure of denomination risk. CDS are NOT easily comparable internationally, unless eg one Eurozone country vs another, or one EM vs another in USD.

Comment: thank you :) would it be then any mistake if i will convert all cds to PLN to simplify?